# Access emitted data from a socket(Socket.io) anywhere

Tags: angularjs, node.js, socket.io

This is my first attempt at using Socket.io
I'm creating an api to emit some data. It work's fine.
Here is the code I think needs to be modified :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));  
app.get('/', function(req, res,next) {  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
});
```

In reference to the above code, the data is being successfully emitted to the index.html file. The port I have used is 4200. So if I enter localhost:4200 in the browser I'm able to see the data being displayed in the index.html file. Now I want to use localhost:4200 in my angular js project to get the data but instead I get the html contents of the index.html file.

Here is the snippet from my angularjs code:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $http.get("localhost:4200").success(function(response) {
console.log(response);

  })
}, 500);
```

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should display the response in question for a better help. thanks.

Comment: there's no error. When I enter localhost:4200 in browser then I can see the data but when I use this to get data using angular js then it logs the code of the html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by adding the following angular snippet :

```
$scope.server = "100.20.32.20"; //Ip of my machine
     $scope.socket = io('http://' + server + ':4200');
 socket.on('broad', function(data) {
console.log($scope.data);});
```